# How to mock out remote_ip in a Rspec helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a helper spec that says the following:
`expect(request).to receive(:remote_ip).and_return('1.2.3.4')`

Running the tests, they pass, but with a warning:

WARNING: An expectation of `:remote_ip` was set on `nil`. To allow expectations on `nil` and suppress this message, set `config.allow_expectations_on_nil` to `true`. To disallow expectations on `nil`, set `config.allow_expectations_on_nil` to `false`.

I've tried using helper.request and controller.request, but then the tests fails: `undefined method remote_ip for nil:NilClass`

How do you mock out your ip address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

You can set the `remote_ip` in the helper with `controller.request.remote_addr = '1.2.3.4'`.

**Example**

*Helper file:*

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def ip
    request.remote_ip
  end
end
```

*Spec file:*

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ApplicationHelper, type: :helper do
  describe '#ip' do
    it 'returns the IP' do
      controller.request.remote_addr = '1.2.3.4'

      expect(helper.ip).to eql '1.2.3.4'
    end
  end
end
```

### Explanation

Helper specs mix in `ActionView::TestCase::Behavior`. This provides a `helper` object which mixes in the helper module being spec'd, along with `ApplicationHelper`. (In this case the module being spec'd is the `ApplicationHelper`).

When the helper spec is executed is sets the `controller` object to an `ActionView::TestCase::TestController`. The `request` object on this test controller is an `ActionController::TestRequest`.

Using the `#remote_addr=` setter on the test request, sets the `"REMOTE_ADDR"` key in the `@env` instance variable. The `remote_ip` uses the same `"REMOTE_ADDR"` key in the `@env` instance variable to retrieve the IP.

Answer (score 11):

You can use env key for the method arguments that will contain `"REMOTE_ADDR"` key:

```rb
post path, params: params, env: { "REMOTE_ADDR": your_desired_ip }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
before do
  request.env['REMOTE_ADDR'] = '59.152.62.114'
end
```

This will resolve your problem. However, if you have used the ip in a private method of your controller can check out [this link:](https://medium.com/@tamal.chakraborty_20403/write-rspecs-to-test-request-remote-ip-in-private-method-of-a-controller-ruby-on-rails-274f2517601e)